# Yet another Vowelburgers™ riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find other Vowelburgers™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion)</sup>*

I ordered 5 plain Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | cave |
| E | risk |
| I | information |
| O | slash |
| U | saving |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is

> B and T buns
>  BAT - found in a cave
>  BET - a risk
>  BIT - information in a computer
>  BOT - SLASH is used to build bots
>  BUT - saving is a synonym of but

Comment: yes it is. How do you solve this riddles so fast?

Comment: Because they are very easy. This one took me about three seconds but of course it was already solved before I saw it. (In this case: look at the second row, think of a short word with a related meaning and the correct vowel, check the others, done.)

Comment: Got to agree with @GarethMcCaughan here - these puzzles basically involve solving 5 crossword-like clues where you already know the middle letter and have the additional helping hand that working out one clue correctly gives you all the others immediately. It's not 5 times the difficulty, if anything it's one fifth of it... Still, a nice idea originally. Not sure it really has that much longevity though...